# How to Organize Comments into a Grid on Emacs?

Tags: comment, automation

I see this done a lot. Don't know what it's called. Don't know how to do it.

See how the comments are all lined up?

```
int myNum = 5;               // Integer (whole number)
float myFloatNum = 5.99f;    // Floating point number
char myLetter = 'D';         // Character
boolean myBool = true;       // Boolean
String myText = "Hello";     // String
```

I am positive people aren't holding down the space key to get these comments lined up. What magic are they using?

Answer (score 7):

`align-regexp` is the interactive function that you can use. Here's how you do it

1. Select the region that you want to apply the indent
2. `M-x align-regexp` which will prompt you for a regexp
3. Enter `//` and press enter

Answer (score 2):

Language modes usually work with the `comment-*` functions in`newcomment.el` to allow such things (and more).

E.g. assume that the above is a snippet of Javascript code and that the buffer is indeed in `Javascript` mode (check the mode line to see if that is indeed the case). Then go to some line and type `M-;`: that will align the comment on a fixed column (the global default is column 32, but language modes are free to set up their own value - do `C-h v comment-column` to see the doc string of the variable that controls this).

The [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/) contains a chapter on [Editing Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Programs.html) which contains a section on [Manipulating comments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comments.html). I highly recommend that you go through this section for this particular question and the whole chapter if you are going to be using Emacs as a programming editor.